# How to specialize methods for multiple types at once

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have code like this:

```
template< class T >
struct Value
{
    /* quite a lot of other functions which I do not want to specialize, too */
    void print( void );
};

template<> void Value<          short int >::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value<                int >::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value<           long int >::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value< unsigned short int >::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value< unsigned       int >::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value< unsigned  long int >::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }

template<> void Value<       float >::print() { std::cout << "is floating point" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value<      double >::print() { std::cout << "is floating point" << std::endl; }
template<> void Value< long double >::print() { std::cout << "is floating point" << std::endl; }

template< class T > void Value<T>::print() { std::cout << "unsupported type" << std::endl; }

int main( void )
{
    Value< float  >().print();
    Value< double >().print();
    Value< short  >().print();
    Value<   char >().print();
}
```

Output:

```
is floating point
is floating point
is integral
unsupported type
```

I want to change this in order to reduce code duplication, especially, because the code body is much longer than a simple `std::cout`. To illustrate the direction I want to go, the simplest idea coming to mind would be to use macros:

```
#define TMP(T) \
template<> void Value<T>::print() { std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl; }
TMP(          short int )
TMP(                int )
TMP(           long int )
TMP( unsigned short int )
TMP( unsigned       int )
TMP( unsigned  long int )
#undef TMP
#define TMP(T) \
template<> void Value<T>::print() { std::cout << "is floating point" << std::endl; }
TMP(       float )
TMP(      double )
TMP( long double )
#undef TMP
```

But I want to get it to work using C++11 template magic. I already tried using `std::enable_if`, but I just can't get it to work. E.g. this

```
template< class T >
void Value<
    typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, T >::type
>::print( void )
{
    std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;;
}
```

gives me

```
test.cpp:26:24: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Value<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value, T>::type>’
 >::type >::print( void )
                        ^
test.cpp:14:8: error: declaration of ‘struct Value<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value, T>::type>’
 struct Value
```

and using `std::enable_if` on the return type:

```
template< class T >
typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value, void >::type
Value<T>::print( void )
{
    std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;;
}
```

gives me:

```
test.cpp:41:1: error: prototype for ‘typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<_Tp>::value, void>::type Value<T>::print()’ does not match any in class ‘Value<T>’
 Value<T>::print( void )
 ^
test.cpp:16:17: error: candidate is: static void Value<T>::print()
     static void print( void );
```

Of course there are many similar questions already:

- http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/151879/
- [match multiple types for template specialization resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285975/match-multiple-types-for-template-specialization-resolution)
- [Template specialization for multiple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627331/template-specialization-for-multiple-types)
- [How to do one explicit specialization for multiple types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280070/how-to-do-one-explicit-specialization-for-multiple-types)

But they often are about simple functions, not methods of templated classes. Also they often don't strictly separate declaration and definition as I want to.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098372/template-partial-specialization-for-multiple-types-overriding-member-function) questions sounds very similar, but it specializes the method not in respect to the struct/class template argument, but in respect to another template argument.

I just can't seem to apply the answers to my specific problem, because of the aforementioned errors. Also I don't want to specialize the whole class, because the class itself shares many methods which are identical for all types T. I don't want to trade one copy-paste code for another.

Bonus for explaining why the two error messages happen. What rule am I breaking. To me it seems that `...::type` isn't substituted at all with `T` or `void`.

Comment: i think that the error of 1st case is that it's actually not a template specialization of value: `A function with the same name and the same argument list as a specialization is not a specialization` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Answer (score 4):

You could use tag dispatch. Define your tags:

```
namespace tag {

struct integral{};
struct floating{};
struct error{};

}
```

Define their mapping from various types:

```
namespace detail
{

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct get_tag : tag::error{};

template<typename T>
struct get_tag<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>> : tag::integral{};

template<typename T>
struct get_tag<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>> : tag::floating{};

}
```

And define your function for each supported tag:

```
void print(tag::error){
    std::cout << "unsupported type" << std::endl;
}
void print(tag::integral){
    std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;
}
void print(tag::floating){
    std::cout << "is floating" << std::endl;
}
```

While forwarding to it from your static method:

```
template< class T >
struct Value
{
    static void print( void ){
        ::print(detail::get_tag<T>{});
    }
};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AslD9iZ7QQMS9zhR)

This will work, but you want `char` not to be treated as an integral, so you may want to define your own trait, that only one of the listed traits (explained in more detail + C++11 version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40496746/2456565)):

```
template<typename T, typename... Others>
struct is_any : std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Others>...>
{
};
```

Now you can write the following for your integral tag

```
template<typename T>
struct get_tag<T, std::enable_if_t<
        is_any<T, short, int, long, unsigned short, unsigned, unsigned long>::value>> : tag::integral{};
```

and the result will be exactly as you wanted.

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/6AG4KAxYNg5yK3GH)

---

If your want to make your `print`s member functions, you can make them templates to avoid compile errors for unsupported types:

```
template< class T >
struct Value
{
    static void print( void ){
        Value obj;
        obj.print(detail::get_tag<T>{});
    }
private:
    template<typename U = T>
    void print(tag::error){
        std::cout << "unsupported type" << std::endl;
    }
    template<typename U = T>
    void print(tag::integral){
        std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;
    }
    template<typename U = T>
    void print(tag::floating){
        std::cout << "is floating" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/yRIqXspjennEgC2S)

---

Alternatively, in C++1z you can use `constexpr if`:

```
static void print( void ){
    using this_tag = detail::get_tag<T>;
    if constexpr(std::is_base_of<tag::floating, this_tag>::value) {
        std::cout << "is floating" << std::endl;
    } else if constexpr(std::is_base_of<tag::integral, this_tag>::value) {
        std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "unsupported type" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/JOJnx6ZZfgMFHcyi)

Comment: Is it possible to also make this solution work for non-static member functions? I mean, I'd have to define `print(tag:....)` as (private) members for all types, which may lead to problems if argument and member-variable types do not match.

Comment: @mxmlnkn check the edit, I'll edit with a C++1z solution in a sec

Comment: just a nitch: since c++14, you could define 
```
template<typename T, typename... Others>
constexpr bool is_any_v= std::disjunction<std::is_same<T, Others>...>::value;
```

Answer (score 2):

To allow SFINAE for your struct, you have to add extra parameter:

```
template<class T, typename AlwaysVoid = void>
struct Value;
```

And then

```
template<class T>
struct Value<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
{
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << "is integral" << std::endl;;
    }
};
```

Comment: As I understand, this solution makes it necessary to redefine the whole struct with many other functions, though. `I don't want to trade one copy-paste code for another.`. Or could you make me see how I could apply this to: `struct Value { /* many functions */ void print(); }`

Comment: @mxmlnkn: Indeed you have to redefine the whole struct, but if you have common code, you might use inheritance to avoid the duplication.